# TFS excludes some files from checkin

Tags: build, tfs, checkin

I use TFS for my project and I have set up gated checkin. I changed one of the interfaces and I made the changes to the class that implements it as well. Then tried to check in, but I received a message that says build failed. Error was: [class] doesn't implement the interface member [interface]. Then I tried to build it on my local machine and everything succeeded. I tried to checkin again, but it failed again.

So I found the problem later, that the interface I made was in the list of files that going to be checkin, but the class I made changes was in excluded list. That cause the build to fail. I am sure that when I checkin on solution level not just the interface.

My question is why that class was in excluded list? Did anyone else had this issue before?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have never seen Visual Studio automatically put files on the exclude list for any reason.

Comment: I guess the class already exists in TFS, right? The only thing I could imagine is, that you start the checkin from the interface file or from Source Control Explorer by right clicking the file/folder. Doing it that way, TeamExplorer looks recursively down the structure for other checkouts, but if your class is in a parallel folder, it will be excluded from checkin.

Comment: @MikeR you are right, if files are in two different folders one might not get checked in if you say check in in one folder, but I can verify that I did checkin on solution level. Because there was some other files which are out of those folders. This might be a bug?

Comment: Is the class file listed in the pending changes? As edit or add? If it is not listed, than it is not known to TFS, so you have to add it. If it is already in TFS, but still not listed, maybe it is not mapped in the workspace, due to cloaks or so?

Comment: @MikeR yes class is added to tfs. Do you think build might cloak the file? I use gated check in.

Comment: Depends on the workspace of the Build Definition, but if it is already on the excluded list when checking in, than it shouldn't be the issue. Unfortunately I have no other idea at the moment and no chance to reproduce it here.

Comment: @MikeR yes that is the problem. I can't reproduce it on my computer too. It happened only one time.